# Travis allow_failures AND condition

Tags: travis-ci

I have a travis build file that looks like as described below (retracted). With allow_failures I would like to select rows from build matrix to meet condition 
go=tip AND JOB=check
However travis evaluates it as 
go=tip OR JOB=check

Is there a way to achieve the AND condition for my specific case?

```
go:
    - 1.8
    - 1.9
    - tip

env:
    global:
        - GOARCH=amd64
    matrix:
        - JOB=docker
        - JOB=deb
        - JOB=rpm
        - JOB=check

matrix:
    allow_failures:
        - go: tip
        - env: JOB=check
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution received here

matrix:
    allow_failures:
        - go: tip
          env: JOB=check

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/10114